# JavaFX, Operations on the data displayed in the TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible that when the data is read from the database to display them in ObservableList TableView turn iterating? I would like to before displaying each line of operation was performed.

```
1. operation on line 1
2. display line 1 in tableview
3. operation on line 2
4. display line 2 in tableview
... and so on.
```

Everything will happen in background thread (Service or Task?)
Operation will search the existence of a key and assign values.

When everything will be loaded when editing data in the TableView is it possible substitution of only one line in the thread so as not to overload the entire view? To all worked fast and well.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. If the question is if you can display some of the data the answer is yes - just insert the data to the table's `items` property when it's ready.

Comment: `tableView.setItems(data);` In this way you can add the data to display. In this case, you need to process everything and just display. I would like to process and display line by line, not all at once. There is a possibility?

Comment: In this way I could edit dynamically selected rows and load data in the background smoothly and without lock time

Comment: Instead of using `setItems`, keep the `items` list the same, and whenever you have a new row of data do `tableView.getItems().add(row)`

Comment: Can I do so that the row will be iteratively accept the values of ObservableList and display the tableView as long as it lasted loop?

Answer (score 1):

I preparde for you some code, i hope it is that what you need. 
The general thought is that you must use new thread and use Task class.
Here you can read more about this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

```
public class Main extends Application {
  private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
  ArrayList<Person> listPerson = new ArrayList<>(); //this list can be filled from database
  private ObservableList<Person> data;

  public Main() {
    listPerson.add(new Person("Ania"));
    listPerson.add(new Person("Kasia"));
    listPerson.add(new Person("Monika"));
    listPerson.add(new Person("Jola"));
    listPerson.add(new Person("Ewa"));
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listPerson);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    //Use new thread where you can proceed your data and add dynamically to the TableVIew
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
      @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (Person person : listPerson) {
          System.out.println("Do something with person: " + person);
          synchronized (this) {
            this.wait(3000);
            table.getItems().add(person);
            System.out.println(person + " added to table. Do the next one \n");
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
  }

  public class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;

    public Person(String fName) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
      firstName.set(fName);
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
      return firstName.getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

It works like on this picture:

[image]

Comment: And is it possible that when each row was stowrzony a new thread? When you have everything in one even load a large number of rows take a little bit. And not the end of it runs in the background. Until you load it all flashes. A cells are editable and should easily be edited without waiting to load all data.

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly. You want to load each row in new thread? And when the data are loading you want to edit them in this same time? In my example I added wait(3000), and it works slowly, but usually it will be so quick that after open ViewTable everything will be visible and loading will be finished. I don't know how i can contact with you, maybe in polish language it will be better ;)